# Identifying monetary values in round brackets (CSS)

Tags: html, css

So I have these codes, that work wonderfully, when the monetary values are clean:

```css
td[data-monetary-amount]:after {
  content: attr(data-monetary-amount);
  color: green;
}

td[data-monetary-amount^="-"]:after {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td data-monetary-amount="+23"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-monetary-amount="-20"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The above code works great when the values start with "+" or "-".

My question is, how to identify values that are in round brackets?

For example:

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td data-monetary-amount="(+23)"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td data-monetary-amount="(-20)"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I'm getting data (with rounded brackets) from external websites with xpath, so there's no way to remove those round brackets.

The only logical way I could think of for this to work is to somehow skip the "(" or ignore them to identify the monetary values.

Any help would be appreciated.

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add some attribute selectors when the value starts with `(+` or `(-`

```css
td[data-monetary-amount]:after,
td[data-monetary-amount^="(+"],
td[data-monetary-amount^="+"] {
  content: attr(data-monetary-amount);
  color: green;
}

td[data-monetary-amount^="(-"]:after,
td[data-monetary-amount^="-"]:after {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td data-monetary-amount="(+23)"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-monetary-amount="(-20)"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It worked, Actually, I have tried that, but it didn't worked first, then I noticed it also imports a space in front of the"(-", so I added the space " (-" and it worked perfectly. Thanks a lot.